# How can I backup a relational database into MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am using a NoSQL database ([MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB)), and I want to back up a relational database (SQL, [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)) into a NoSQL database...

I have read the manual inside & out - I read no reference on how to do so...

How can that be done? Can you show an example?

Comment: What you're asking doesn't really make sense.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Want to back up SQL database via mongo

Comment: I have two environments MS SQL and MySQL is it possibly to back up to Mongo---- Or do I have to migrate the databases to Mongo via importing or timestamp

Comment: What does "back up" to MongoDB mean?  Are you trying to import data, save a binary backup dump of another database, ...?  If you are trying to import data into MongoDB, you almost certainly don't want to mirror the structure of your relational data and need to reconsider [how to model the data](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try MongoVUE. This tool allows to migrate all your MySQL data to MongoDB; I used it so many times. Click [here](http://www.mongovue.com/downloads/) to download it.

If the above link does not work, copy paste http://www.mongovue.com/downloads/ into the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a script (I suggest Python for that) that connects to the RDBMS you wish to back up, creates a meaningful document out of the rows (or better yet, the objects you represent in said database) and then inserts them into MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

While migrating any relational database to a [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database, we need to define an agenda like [Extract, Transform and Load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) (ETL), and for ETL to work we need to understand it first.
**
Agenda:

-Migration Roadmap

-Schema Design

-Application Integration

-Data Migration

-Operational Considerations

-Resources to get started.

**
You can get a clear idea about the migration process from the below images:

[image]

[image]